# set background Image to whole application in android

Tags: android, background-image, android-theme

I want to set background image to my application in android. So my application already has a theme set in my manifest file like this

```
 <application   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

Now this was implemented from the themes of android package.

Now i want to add a background image to my entire application how can i do it.

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitleBar.BackgroundImage">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bitzer_background</item>
</style>
```

I want the Theme.NoTitleBar as well.

Comment: If you have your image resource in drawable folder you can refer them as follows:
android:background="@drawable/resource_name".

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have changed the style below, by doing this I am overriding the Theme.NoTitlteBar

```
<style name="Background" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now my manifest file looks like this:

```
<application  android:theme="@style/Background"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use styles to achieve this 
Check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)

Create a theme with your background and use that theme.

Comment: I tried this solution, but following this method would remove the Theme.NoTitleBar which has to be applied and i must add the background image having Theme.NoTitleBar also applied.